# Linux VPN Server That Supports Windows 7 Native VPN Client

Tags: vpn

Can anyone recommend a Linux VPN service that supports connections from the native Windows 7 VPN client? I don't want to install any weird custom software on my machines that are going to connect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pptp would probably be the easiest, but ipsec l2tp with openswan should work too

Comment: Can OpenVPN do it?

Comment: OpenVPN work only if you intall the OpenVPN client software, there's no native windows implementation in Windows 7

Comment: Ended up using PPTPD and it is win